# When should you use Task.Run() rather than await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am storing the state of my data model. I clone the data model and then want to have it written to "disk" asynchronously.

Should I be using Task.Run() which runs it on a background thread?
Or should I just make it an async function and not await on it? (this will make it run on the UI thread)

Similar stuff to this, but my question is a bit different:
[async Task.Run with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460290/async-task-run-with-mvvm)

And what is the criteria to decide which to choose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Task.Run` for CPU-based work that you want to run on a thread pool thread.

In your situation, you want to do I/O based work without blocking the UI, so `Task.Run` won't get you anything (unless you don't have asynchronous I/O APIs available).

As a side note, you definitely *do* want to `await` this work. This makes error handling much cleaner.

So, something like this should suffice:

```
async void buttonSaveClick(..)
{
  buttonSave.Enabled = false;

  try
  {
    await myModel.Clone().SaveAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Display error.
  }

  buttonSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is on pause, so I definitely don't want to show any error to the user. They wouldn't be able to do much with it anyways, and the app would recover anyways if it wasn't saved (more of a cache if anything anyways).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it matters. As far as I know, both methods get dispatched to a thread in the thread pool.

Using `async` will **make the async method run on a background thread and continue on the thread that started it when the async method is finished**. You can imagine the compiler seeing the await keyword, put the awaited method in a background thread and wiring up events to notice when the asynch method is finished. Therefore this might be the better choice if you want to show a UI change because of the successful save, and because this is lesser code of course.

`Task.Run()` would be nicer when you for any reason don't want to put the code in an `async` method, for example because you want the calling method itself not be async. Also, there's lesser event marshaling involved, but I heavily doubt that there's any performance difference at all.

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure? I thought the whole architecture of async was to resume executing *on the same thread*. Otherwise it would not "make it easier on developers".

Comment: From [TAP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957): "If a SynchronizationContext is associated with the thread executing the asynchronous method at the time of suspension (e.g. SynchronizationContext.Current is non-null), the resumption of the asynchronous method will take place on that same SynchronizationContext through usage of the context’s Post method. Otherwise, it will rely on whatever System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler was current at the time of suspension (typically this will be TaskScheduler.Default, which targets the .NET ThreadPool)"

Comment: That's what I said. The async method execution is taken to another thread from the threadpool, and when that finishes, the result gets back to the calling thread where the rest of the method finishes.

Comment: @Akku: you're answer is ambiguous since you first state that both methods will be dispatched to a thread in the thread pool. Then you state that when using `async`, the continuation is executed on the same thread that started the async call which isn't necessarily true.

Comment: So... just so i understand this correctly, it will only run on a threadpool thread if we were already on some threadpool thread (and not the main ui thread) when the original async method was called. Correct?

Comment: No. The async function will run on a ThreadPool thread no matter what. The result of the async task will be made available on the thread that started the async task, no matter if it's the main thread, a threadpool thread or a thread you created and started yourself. But async is clearly *made* for use on the main thread.